# Loading JSON into BigQuery: Field is sometimes an array and sometimes a string

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-platform, struct, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load JSON data to BigQuery. The excerpt of my data causing problems looks like this:

```
 [{"Value":"123","Code":"A"},{"Value":"000","Code":"B"}]
 {"Value":"456","Code":"A"}
 [{"Value":"123","Code":"A"},{"Value":"789","Code":"C"},{"Value":"000","Code":"B"}]
 {"Value":"Z","Code":"A"}
```

I have defined the schema for this field to be:

```
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "Code",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "Value",
        "type": "STRING"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "Properties",
    "type": "RECORD"
  }
```

But I'm having trouble successfully extracting the string and array values into one repeated field. This SQL will successfully extract the string values:

```
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string,'$.Properties.Code') as Code,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string,'$.Properties.Value') as Value
```

And this SQL will successfully extract the array values:

```
  ARRAY(
    SELECT
      STRUCT(
        JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Properties_Array,'$.Code') AS Code,
        JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Properties_Array,'$.Value') AS Value
      )
    FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_string,'$.Properties')) Properties_Array)
  AS Properties
```

I am trying to find a way to have BigQuery to read this string as a one element array instead of preprocessing the data. Is this possible in #StandardSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` as (
  SELECT '{"Properties":[{"Value":"123","Code":"A"},{"Value":"000","Code":"B"}]}' json_string UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"Properties":{"Value":"456","Code":"A"}}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"Properties":[{"Value":"123","Code":"A"},{"Value":"789","Code":"C"},{"Value":"000","Code":"B"}]}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"Properties": {"Value":"Z","Code":"A"}}'  
)
SELECT json_string, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT STRUCT(
        JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Properties,'$.Code') AS Code,
        JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Properties,'$.Value') AS Value
      )
    FROM UNNEST(IFNULL(
      JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_string,'$.Properties'), 
      [JSON_EXTRACT(json_string,'$.Properties')])) Properties
  ) AS Properties  
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch @mikhail-berlyant! Worked like a charm. I tried a few combinations of UDFs, CASE statements and CTEs and had a hunch the solution would involve checking for a null array.